# How can I share my database using IP Address?

Tags: java, netbeans, xampp

```
 import java.sql.Connection; 
 import java.sql.DriverManager; 
 import javax.swing.JOptionPane;  
  public class Database {      
      public static Connection con = null;      
      public static Connection connectDB() {         
       try {             
         Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");            
         Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.8:3306/registerdb",                     "root", "");  
     //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Connection Successful");             
     return con;         
    } catch (Exception e) {             
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);        
     return null;   
  }    
  }  
 }
```

How I make my finish program share to others locally or using the internet and how to use the IP address for it? I'm using NetBeans for my java programming and XAMPP for my database.
Please help me.. THanks

Comment: What, exactly, do you mean by "share"?

Comment: when I put my program to another computer and by using ip address they can also connect to the database I use..

Answer (score 0):

Install db server on any computer, get servers IP address and port and pass that information to `DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://IP:port/dbname")`
Its best to use property file to store IP and port and read it when creating connection so it can be easily changed without changing the code.

Comment: Thanks Mladen Savić. may I ask what is the proper syntax?

Answer (score 0):

Your program should work as it is on multiple machines as long as they are in the same local network (as you are using local IP address).

If they are not able to connect to DB, following can be the possible reasons:

1. DB is not configured to allow connection from another machine. You
   can grant it using following syntax:
   grant all on db-name.* to username@'%' identified by 'password'
2. Your firewall is blocking income 3306 port requests. Open the port
   for incoming requests.

Comment: Thanks kishor borate. can i ask what is the proper or what are the steps?

Comment: Check if you can use any ORM to interact with your database. It saves lot of efforts of managing connections, querying and reading query results. 

As for the connection problem you specified following things you can check:
#1. Login to mysql and run the SQL query I mentioned in option 1 with valid credentials

#2. run telnet <ip-address>:port from other machine. If it returns any error, you might have your 3600 port blocked. Allow incoming requests to 3600 port in your firewall.